# Android ripple difference between 5.0 and 6.0

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I've added a ripple animation to a button, it works on API 21 (5.0) but not on 23 (6.0).

Here is a gif, top is a 6.0 emulator, bottom is a 5.0 one. I'd like the top one to look like the bottom one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/USDGX.jpg

This is the drawable source (in v21-drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/yellow_dark">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_yellow_rectangle_light" />
</ripple>
```

This is the normal source (in drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/shape_yellow_rectangle_dark" />
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/shape_yellow_rectangle_dark" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_yellow_rectangle_light" />
</selector>
```

The rectangle source (shape_yellow_rectangle_light.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius" />
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/button_border" android:color="@color/yellow_light" />
    <solid android:color="@color/yellow_light" />
 </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

What did I do wrong? Cant find any documentation on this.

Comment: I am facing exact same situation when implementing ripple view animation in navigation drawer. It's a shame to see that no one replied to your question since April. By any chance, did you come to know about the reason or a workaround? any official announcement from Google?